# Spotify iOS SDK: Behavior with non-premium accounts

Tags: ios, spotify

From the Spotify iOS SDK documentation:

"Please also note that streaming of full-length tracks is only available to your users who have a Spotify Premium subscription."

However, with the SDK integrated into our app, I can login using a non-Premium account and tracks playback in their entirety.

Also, using the non-Premium login, advertisements never play prior to the start of a track, as one would expect with a non-Premium account.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Many Thanks!